# difference between @Component and @App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, components

I have seen `@App and @Component` been used in the same way. example is

```
@App({
  templateUrl:'app.html'
})

@Component({
  templateUrl:'app.html'
})
```

I want to know if there is any difference between them, and when do i use each of them?

Comment: maybe check out this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472920/what-do-the-decorators-page-component-and-app-mean-in-ionic-2-apps.