# What do the decorators @page, @component and @app mean in ionic 2 apps?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, ionic2

I've seen *@app* and *@page* and *@component* used seemingly interchangeably and i don't know what the difference is.

The ionic2 documentation is very bad on this so what is the fundamental difference between these decorators for ionic 2 apps, and when would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Page and @App are deprecated decorators you must focus only on @Component

angular2 use something called ReflectMetadata, basically a decorator add some important metadata to your class